# CloudKit always run into error while save information Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I always run a error if i try to save a test information into `CloudKit`

my code is

```
   super.viewDidLoad()

        let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let todoRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "cloudKit_TESTSTATUS")
        todoRecord.setValue("TEST DATA", forKey: "status")

        publicDB.saveRecord(todoRecord) { savedRecord, error in
            print("error")
        }
  }
```

My database look like

[image]

Could someone explain me what i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.privateCloudDatabase

    let todoRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "cloudKit_TESTSTATUS")
    todoRecord.setValue("TEST DATA", forKey: "status")
    publicData.saveRecord(todoRecord, completionHandler: { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

    })

}
```